# iOS CommonJS module returns "undefined is not a constructor" error

Tags: ios, module, titanium, appcelerator, commonjs

I'm trying to create an iOS Titanium Module using a pre-compiled CommonJS module. As the README file says:

> All JavaScript files in the assets directory are IGNORED except if you create a
>   file named "com.moduletest.js" in this directory in which case it will be
>   wrapped by native code, compiled, and used as your module. This allows you to
>   run pure JavaScript modules that are pre-compiled.

I've created the file like this:

```
function ModuleTest(url){
 if(url){
   return url;
 }
}
exports.ModuleTest = ModuleTest;
```

I'm using the 5.1.2.GA SDK (also tried with 5.3.0.GA) and I can build the module successfully either with `python build.py` or `titanium build --platform iOS --build-only`.
Then, in my test app doing:

```
var test = require('com.moduletest');
var url = new test.ModuleTest('http://url');
```

Gives me this error:

[image: undefined is not a constructor]

undefined is not a constructor.
I've been trying a lot of alternatives but nothing seems to work and I didn't find any help on documentation about pre-compiled JS modules for iOS. Actually, the same process works great for Android!
Do you have some idea why?

My environment:

XCode 7.3.1

Operating System
  Name                        - Mac OS X
  Version                     - 10.11.5
  Architecture                - 64bit
  # CPUs                      - 8
  Memory                      - 16.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             - 0.12.7
  npm Version                 - 2.11.3

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   - 4.2.6
  Core Package                - 5.3.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 - 5.0.9
  node-appc Version           - 0.2.31

Maybe this is something related to my Node version or appc CLI, not sure =/

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you put your file `com.moduletest.js`?

Comment: Hi Brenton, I put it in the assets folder moduleTest/assets/com.moduletest.js
http://i.imgur.com/4OW2i86.png

Comment: For commonjs modules, you can just put them directly in your app project.  Try putting that file in `/app/lib/com.moduletest.js' of your app.

Comment: Solution below by @RenePot should get you going.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions.

1) Don't put it in assets, but in the `/app/lib` folder as others have mentioned.

2) wrap it as an actual commonjs module, like the [module I wrote](http://github.com/Topener/To.ImageCache)

In both cases, you can just use `require('modulename')`. In case 2 you will need to add it to the `tiapp.xml` file just like any other module.

The path of your file will come in `/modules/commonjs/modulename/version/module.js` or something similar. My linked module will show you the requirements and paths needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different pattern that works excellent:

First a small snippet from my "module":

```
Stopwatch = function(listener) {
    this.totalElapsed = 0; // * elapsed number of ms in total
    this.listener = (listener != undefined ? listener : null); // * function to receive onTick events
};

Stopwatch.prototype.getElapsed = function() {
    return this.totalElapsed;
};

module.exports = Stopwatch;
```

And then this is the way I use it:

```
var StopWatch = require('utils/StopWatch');
var stopWatch = new StopWatch(listenerFunction);
console.log('elapsed: ' + stopWatch.getElapsed());
```